# How to split values in a nested dictionary by characters

Tags: python

Lets say I have a nested dictionary

```
nested_dict={"dict1":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3;value4"}}
```

Now I want to split value3 and value 4 under the same key like this,

```
nested_dict={"dict1":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2",  'key3': ['value3', 'value4']}}
```

What would be the best way to do so in Python?

Comment: Your desired output is a little strange — `value3` and `value4` will be concatenated. So `nested_dict['dict1']['key3']` will be `value3value4`. Is that what you really want? Or are you expecting something more like `'key3': ['value3', 'value4']`?

Comment: Is there any way I have them under the same key, so when I call "key3", I get "value 3" "value4"?

Comment: `...so when I call "key3"` what? What happened when you use `"key3"`. That's my question. Is that a list? If so, it's just `nested_dict['dict1']['key3'] = nested_dict['dict1']['key3'].split(';')`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I am expecting something more like      'key3': ['value3', 'value4']

Answer (score 1):

use the fact that `dict` is mutable and you can recursively change anything under the sun :P

```
nested_dict={"dict1":{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3;value4"}}
def sol(d):
    for i in d:
        if type(d[i]) is dict:
            sol(d[i])
        else:
            d[i] = d[i].split(';')
            if len(d[i])==1: d[i] = d[i][0]
sol(nested_dict)
print(nested_dict)
```

```
{'dict1': {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': ['value3', 'value4']}}
```